# Adverb of time for showing a certain short period in the past

Tags: word-choice

> Sentence A: Where's the ring you had **earlier**?
>
> Sentence B: Where's the ring you had **a while ago**?

I want to know what corrections would be made to these two sentences, and which one is better to use (as a native English speaker would say).

Comment: Both sound okay to me. (The second one sounds somewhat better.) I think it's more likely to hear *"Where's that ring?"* or *"Where's the ring you just got?"* (sb. gave it to you), or *"Where's the ring you just bought?"* (you bought it yourself), or *"Where's the ring I gave you?"* or they might specify the time, e.g. *"Where's the ring you bought two months ago?"* I'm looking forward to hearing from native speakers too. ;)

Comment: For either of these constructions, the simple past “had” would be used. Also note that in written English, punctuation is not preceded by a space.

Comment: @DamkerngT They do not sound okay because you cannot "have" (present tense) something "earlier" (time before now).

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung Oh punctuation is preceded by a space, just one that is much narrower than the one in "say ?". :-)

Comment: @Kaz, Thank you. Instinctively, I felt that something was wrong somewhere but I couldn't tell where, so they sounded okay to me then. But I think I was right that I didn't dare to post it as an answer. ;)

Comment: The only punctuation I can think of that is preceded by a space is a hyphen or dash. Colons, commas, periods, question marks, etc all immediately follow the preceding character with no space. Well, an opening quote mark would have a preceding space and no following space, to "tie" it to the thing being quoted. Dashes have a space before and after. Everything else I can think of has no space before and one space after. There's an old rule that the punctuation that ends a sentence -- ending period, question mark, or exclamation -- is followed by two spaces, but I think this is largely obsolete.

Comment: @DamkerngT. It's not obvious because it's a semantic restriction, not syntactic. "earlier" is essentially in the same syntactic category as "now" or "at the moment", which can be used with a present tense verb.

Comment: @Jay So what do we call that clearance which prevents the punctuation from touching the surrounding characters? Not "space"?

Comment: @Kaz: Oh, wait, you're using two different meanings of the word "space". Of course there is always a certain amount of space between printed characters: we don't mash them all together into one solid block of ink. But for most people typing something, you don't do anything to get that "normal spacing": the computer (or typewriter, in the Dark Ages before computers) just automatically fills in a little gap between each pair of characters. When we say whether to put "space" between letters, digits, or punctuation, we normally mean whether or not you press the space bar. If you are ...

Comment: ... into serious graphic design, you will talk about "kerning", that is, adjusting this gap between characters. You may decide to press characters together or spread them apart because you believe it is more attractive that way, to make the length of lines match, or just to save or fill up space. But that's a different thing from a "normal person" typing a document deciding when to press the space bar and when not. Don't press the space bar before typing a colon, question mark, or period. Period.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either **“earlier”** or **“a while ago”** would be fine in this instance, but would communicate slightly different things.

**“Earlier”** could be any time in the past, but would most likely be used to refer to **the recent past**.

**“A while ago”** could also refer to just about any time span in the past, but would most likely be used to indicate **the more distant past**.

Here are two scenarios to demonstrate what I mean:

> Halfway through the wedding reception, the groom switched from the showy ring they'd used in the ceremony to the more comfortable, understated ring he’d wear from then on.
>
> **“Where's the ring you had on *earlier*?”** asked his cousin.
>
> “I took it off and replaced it with this one about an hour ago.” answered the groom.

> Unbeknownst to her friend Samantha, whom she hadn’t seen for five years, Angela had misplaced a topaz ring on a camping trip three years ago.
>
> **“Where's that ring you had *a while ago*?”** asked Samantha.
>
> “I lost it while trying to fish by hand in the Ozarks.” answered Angela.

Comment: Could you kindly tell me why you used the *past perfect* not the *past simple* in the sentence: "Angela had misplaced a topaz ring on a camping trip three years ago."?

Comment: @learner The entire story—including the set-up—takes place in the past (it’s easier to see in the first example, where I use “switched”, but notice “asked” and “answered” in the dialog). My use of the past perfect is consistent with the first use listed [here](http://www.englishpage.com/verbpage/pastperfect.html). I’m referring to a completed action (losing the ring) that happened before something in the past (this conversation I’m reporting on).